# Getting null pointer exception when trying to fetch data from Sqlite db with helper class object

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, csv-import

I want to fetch data from .csv file,store it into Sqlite db for the very 1st time when app launches.After that fetch data from Sqlite db and show in Expandable list view.But I am getting null pointer exception when I am trying to call methods of DatabaseHelper class using helper class object.

**DatabaseHelper**

```
  `public Cursor getExpandableData() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Category GROUP BY categorydesc";
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }`

  public boolean insertContact(String[] rowData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("DistrictCd", rowData[0]);
    contentValues.put("ProspectId", rowData[1]);
    contentValues.put("categorydesc", rowData[2]);
    contentValues.put("BusinessName", rowData[3]);
    contentValues.put("ph_Phone", rowData[4]);
    contentValues.put("LandMark", rowData[5]);
    contentValues.put("CategoryId", rowData[6]);
    db.insert("Category", null, contentValues);
    // check for data is inserted into db or not
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Category", null);
    int noOfRecords = cursor.getCount();
    // if cursor holding some data then data is inserted successfully
    if (noOfRecords != 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }`
```

`
      **NearByApp calls for only app launch**

```
  `public class NearByApp extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {SharedPreferences prefs =  
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
        // run only once when app has been launched for the 1st time
        csvToSqlite();
        // mark first time has runned.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.commit();
    }`

    `public void csvToSqlite() {
           //code for fetching data from .csv
            String[] RowData = reader.split(",");
            databaseHelper  = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            if (databaseHelper.insertContact(RowData) == true) {
                Log.i("inside csvToSqlite()", " data inserted     successfully");
            } else {
                Log.i("inside csvToSqlite()",
                        " data is not inserted into db");
            }`
```

**MainActivity**

```
         `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Group data//
       databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
       Cursor cursor=databaseHelper.getExpandableData();`
        }`
```

I am getting Exception at

> return db.rawQuery(query, null);

line

> 04-21 14:25:49.810: E/AndroidRuntime(25473): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-21 14:25:49.810: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at com.example.nearbuy.database.DatabaseHelper.getExpandableData(DatabaseHelper.java:308)

Comment: Please format/indent your code properly! What's the NPE you're getting ? from which line is it triggered ? what's the stacktrace ?

Comment: Can you please show us what your logs say??

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.nearbuy.database.DatabaseHelper.getExpandableData(DatabaseHelper.java:308)

Comment: change this line to `databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); ` like this :- `databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());` what is getExpandableData is doing??? may be the error because of that method.

Comment: Modified it as you have suggested..Still i am getting same exception. getExpandableData is fetching data from Sqlite.I am getting exception at             return db.rawQuery(query, null); line

Comment: Then sure your `db` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.csvToSqlite();
```

these lines causing issue because Activity is not running but trying to call method by creating object of `MainActivity`.

So,instead of calling `csvToSqlite()` from create `MainActivity` class move `csvToSqlite()` method  in `NearByApp` class to execute method only once

Comment: I have tried that also.But inside Main activity when i am trying to access helper class method                                                                                 databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
       Cursor cursor=databaseHelper.getExpandableData();                              I am getting null poiner exception for that

Comment: @AkankshaSawarkar: ok then update code using inside MainActivity and also share crash log with question